# Make a menu visible when hovering over an image in CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

When I hover over an image I want to see a menu. I manage to make the menu hidden and then when hovering make it visible, but the problem is that it also becomes visible when hovering around the side of the image. I want the menu to show only when i hovers over the image

HTML

```
{% load static%}
<div class = 'img_wrap'>
        <img src="{% static '/images/rocket.jpg' %}"  class ="image1" alt="My image"> 
        <div class="vertical-menu">
            <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.img__wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
  }

.image1
{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left:300px;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;

}
.vertical-menu a{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left:300px;
    display: block;
    
}    

.vertical-menu a{
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left:300px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    
    
}
.img_wrap:hover .vertical-menu a{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 100;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

".img__wrap" =>".image_wrap"

You wrote the class name wrong

Comment: No, img_wrap is the class name of the div